# VBA - Find all matching and add text and complete with autofill

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have this table:

```
NAME1
NAME1
NAME1
NAME1
NAME2
NAME2
NAME2
```

and need to end up with this

```
NAME1_A1
NAME1_A2
NAME1_A3
NAME1_A4
NAME2_A1
NAME2_A2
NAME2_A3
```

So basically I need to find all the cells that match exactly each other. In this case I would find "NAME1" and then I need to add "_A1" to "_Ax" where x is same as count of found matches. Then it needs to find another match and do the same. So for NAME2 , add A1 - Ax as well.

I was trying to begin with recording macro and then editing it. Afterwards I have tried to write this on my own, however, my I have to admit that I don't even know how to start.
Anyone to help ?

Comment: Sort the column A-Z. In the column next to it add a formula incrementing the number/letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have your data in column A starting in cell A1.

In cell B1, put in the following formula:

```
=A1 & "_A" & COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)
```

Then drag it down.

Now, just `Copy` and `Paste Special` > `Values` on top of your original column and you're done - Then you can delete out the calculation column.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Awesome. It works !  I haven't even thought of such a simple way. Well, sometimes less is more.
Thank You !